# Add extra options to link_to do

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

I would like to pass a parameter with this link_to helper. How do I do that?

```
<%= link_to ('/my_controller/my_action') do %>
    <div>haha</div>
<% end %>
```

The original code I had used the standard text link:

```
<%= link_to("link text", {:controller => 'my_controller', :action => 'my_action', :id => my_id}) %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like in your second example:

```
<%= link_to({:controller => 'my_controller', :action => 'my_action', :id => my_id}) do %>
   My text goes here
<% end %>
```

If you have a path helper for this (i.e. if it's something like `PostsController`'s `show` action) then you could do:

```
<%= link_to post_path(my_id) do %>
  My text goes here
<% end %>
```

Comment: I kept doing this but without any { }. Thank you for your repsonse.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you want to pass options to the `link_to` helper when using a block.

From the documentation at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

This is possible with the following format

```
link_to(options = {}, html_options = {}) do
  # name
end
```

To give you an example and using the code you provided:

```
<%= link_to({:controller => 'my_controller', :action => 'my_action', :id => my_id}) do %>
    <div>haha</div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This doesn't show an example of how to do what OP asked.

Comment: My answer showed the signature to use in order to solve his problem. Added the example...